# getting HTTP 404 error when trying to submit a form in a facebook app

Tags: php, html, facebook, http, post

I am building a Facebook survey, in which there are multiple questions per a random selected friend.

my methodology for doing so is to show a php page with one friend and his/her questions

and when the user submits, it should post to the same php page but with an array containing the left to be shown friends ids.

this is I have such architecture and relevant code:

**home.php - logging into facebook**

**framing.php - managing the survey**

```
$idArray = friends id array...
$pageToReturnTo = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
$q_html = questionnaire($idArray,$pageToReturnTo);
```

**q.php - containing a functions that gets the current survey from db and manipulate it to html**

```
function questionnaire($idArray,$pageToReturnTo){
...
$idArray_imploded = implode(",",$idArray)
$html .= "<form method='POST' action='".$pageToReturnTo."}?idArray=".$idArray_imploded."'>
....
return $html;
}
```

**the problem is that the facebook returns an error like this:**

```
Received HTTP error code 404 while loading http://www.mydomain.com/%7D?idArray=757010120%...
```

1. though I am asking about the php_self in framing.php, I don't see it in the generated url, can someone please explain why?
2. how can I resolve this? if not can you please suggest an alternative?

thanks a million!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you have an extra **`}`** in your $html right before **`?idArray=`**. That's the `%7D` you see in the returned error from Facebook.

```
$html .= "<form method='POST' action='".$pageToReturnTo."?idArray=".$idArray_imploded."'>
```

Also, you should check to ensure that `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` actually contains a value. It looks like it may be empty on your server. There are a few other ways to get the name of the currently running script. For testing you could just replace `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` with the hardcoded name of the php script, just to make sure that your script is actually working.

```
// $pageToReturnTo = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
$pageToReturnTo = 'myscript.php';
```